# Bootstrap 4 - Show modal with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I've got a Button which is supposed to open a bootstrap modal with Javascript function.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="myBtn" onclick="return check_PJ();">PJ</button>
```

Here you can see my modal popup :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="mediumModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mediumModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
         <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">
                 <h5 class="modal-title" id="mediumModalLabel">Insertion de pièce(s) jointe(s)</h5>
                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                 </button>
             </div>
             <form name="form1" method="post" onsubmit="checkform();" action="./MAJ_pj.jsp">

             <input type="hidden" value="<%=ref%>" name="ref">
                 <div class="modal-body">
                     Body ....
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-footer">
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Annuler</button>
                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ajouter</button>
                 </div>
            </form>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

And there is my JS function. I just check if the value("ref") is empty or not in my JSP page. There is all time a value so we all time go in the "else"

```
function check_PJ()
    {
        var returnValue = true;
        var ref = document.getElementById("ref").value;

        if(ref.trim() === "" || ref.trim() == "")
        {
            returnValue = false;
        }
        else
        {
            $('#mediumModal').modal('show')
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
```

I'm stuck with this problem, when I click on the button that open my modal, but the opacity property ".fade") is still 0, so the modal is like invisible ... Maybe I missed something ?

PS : I use Bootstrap 4

Comment: I don't see an element with id `ref`.

Comment: check_PJ and check_Information functions have different names. In this way on button click you will never call the check_Information . Is it correct?

Comment: "ref" is and ID of an input in my JSP page, trust me he is never empty, so in my JS we all time go in "else" condition

Comment: gaetonoM, yep i failed my post sorry, i edit my first post the function is "check_PJ"